# How to troubleshoot a bokeh server using console

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Currently I am displaying a DataTable in a tab on a bokeh server. But I have a function in the main.py file that is expected to import another local python file and execute functions within it. When I call on the function referencing this local python file's function it doesn't execute on the bokeh server but works just fine in a juptyer notebook.

I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me how to get some output to display on the bokeh server console so I can get an idea of what's going on with the bokeh server and why it's not able to apply the function successfully. As currently no errors or useful imformation is displayed on the bokeh server

The function being called upon imports CSVs into a postgresql database and creates the tables if they don't already exist.

```
def cb_import_statements():
    Import_Statements().import_statements()

cb_import_statements()
```

Only difference between the notebook and the server is the last line of displaying the bokeh layout. the call to cb_import_statements() works when it's in a juptyer notebook but doesn't seem to do anything when called using the bokeh server.

I'm sure it's something simple but I haven't been able to find a way to identify why when I call that function it is failing to run.

Comment: Even when I have the tables created and partially populated and call on the function using a button the function cb_import_statements() fails to apply via bokeh server but I can call cb_import_statements() via a notebook without any issues.

Comment: are they inside a main check? Scripts run by `bokeh serve` do not set `__name__`. Also print statements work find to get console output.

Comment: I have print statements and they don't show up on the bokeh server console. They show up just fine in a notebook but not via the bokeh server. I don't currently have a main check in the script. If I put another function inside of cb_import_statements() function it gets executed. It's the Import_Statements().import_statements() that doesn't seem to be executing when run via the bokeh serve command.

Comment: All of this is very strange. I use plain `print` to debug bokeh server apps all the time, almost daily. What platform are you on? Perhaps there is something specific to postgres that is causing a weird interaction? What does `import_statements` do? Also figuring this out is going ot be an exploration, so the mailing list might be a better place than SO:  https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh

Comment: thanks I'll grab all the details when I've got access to the environment again and put up the details on the mailing list.

Comment: I chucked it up on the mailing list @bigreddot as you mentioned. We'll see if someone can figure out what silly mistake I've possibly made :) Thanks for the advice.